# Char array size

Tags: c, arrays, string

What is the difference in the code below? Obviously the first declaration can hold up to 200 characters but what about the second?

```
char name[200] = "Name";
char name[] = "Name";
```

Comment: `'Name'` is an `int`.. Suspect you want `"Name"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first create an array of 200 `char`s and initialize its contents with `{'N','a','m','e','\0', ... }` (the rest is filled with `NUL`s).

The second create an array just large enough to hold `"Name"`, that is, 5 `char`s (one more for the `NUL`)

Besides, you should use double quotes for string literals in C and C++.

Answer (score 3):

First you meant:

```
char name[200] = "Name";
char name[] = "Name";
```

(strings are quoted with `"` not with `'`)

Then the difference is the storage reserved for `name` object in the first case is `200` bytes and in the second case is `5` bytes (that is the string length + `1` byte for the trailing null character).

Comment: Strings end with `\0`

Comment: Four letters in `"Name"` plus one extra character for the NULL terminator `'\0'`.